# How to bind params with raw query mysql yii

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

i am using raw text query to generate results. But in order to avoid sql injection it want to parameterize query on both the variable i.e $from & $to, passed in userStat() function.

```
puclic function userStat($from, $to){
     $sql = "select u.user_id as ID, u.email as Email
            from User u
            where u.type = 'x'
            and u.join_date BETWEEN '$from'  AND '$to'";

    $rawData = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    return $userData  = new CSqlDataProvider($rawData, array(
                'keyField'=>'ID',
            ));
}
```

Now i want to bind $from and $to with text query($sql).

Please help me to figure out this.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `bindParam` then `queryAll()`. Something like below.

```
$sql = "select u.user_id as ID, u.email as Email
        from User u
        where u.type = 'x'
        and u.join_date BETWEEN :start  AND :end";
$rawData = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
$rawData->bindParam(":start", $from, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$rawData->bindParam(":end", $to, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$data = $rawData->queryAll();
```

For details [bindParam](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#binding-parameters). I think it will solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

To bind data, here's what you'd do:

```
pubic function userStat($from, $to){
 $sql = "select u.user_id as ID, u.email as Email
        from User u
        where u.type = 'x'
        and u.join_date BETWEEN :from  AND :to";

$rawData = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->bindValues(array(':from'=>$from, ':to'=>$to));
return $userData  = new CSqlDataProvider($rawData, array(
            'keyField'=>'ID',
        )); }
```

Comment: i have tried this but it is giving following error. CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound